# Unity: What exactly is a "Player"?

Tags: unity-game-engine

While reading the introduction to the Unity game engine, a repeating phrase is the word "Player".

For example: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PublishingBuilds.html

> When building standalone players, the resulting files will vary
>   depending on the build target. For the Windows build target, an
>   executable file (.exe) will be built...

Is a player referring to a specific version of the game that only runs on a specific platform? Or what is it referring to?

Comment: The final App. It "plays" the Unity scene/code/etc